# How can I retrieve an id from the url in Coldfusion?

Tags: url, coldfusion, parameters

I'm updating a site and am struggling to find a way to get an id from the URL. For example I have this:

```
 http://some.html/search.cfm?id=9900000000301
```

How do I get the id value *"9900000000301"* from the URL in Coldfusion8?

I have tried *url.id* plus all sorts of *cgi.query_string* variations, but the number is still out of reach :-(

Thanks for help!

**EDIT**:
If I dump the URL struct, I'm getting this:

```
catch - struct

TYPE: default
VALUE: search
```

Which is not saying much to me.

Comment: `URL.id` should work fine if it is a parameter of the current page. What do you mean by "out of reach"? What value are you getting for `#URL.id#` if not 9900000000301?

Comment: @Leigh - and yes it's the parameter of the page I'm loading and I need to work with the ID.

Comment: No obvious reason it should not work. Post the code used to generate url (or GET form code, etc..)?

Comment: Ok. I have it... I was loading search.cfm?id=.... from which I fired an AJAX request to load some additional content. I had the url check inside the additional content... silly me. In the original page it works :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `url.id` should work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Url.Id *will* work - with one exception.

If you have created a variable called Url, it is possible (in Adobe CF) to "hide" the Url scope, and thus not be able to access it.

For example, if you have a function with an argument called url, referring to url inside that function will refer to Arguments.Url, not the Url scope. If this is the case, you need to rename the argument to be able to access the proper Url scope.

<sub>(Alternatively, switch to [a better CFML engine](http://getrailo.org) where scope names always takes precedence over unscoped variables, and thus scopes cannot be hidden.)</sub>

Comment: Ok. Also good to know. See my comment in the question for what I did wrong. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you are looking to use the data, here are two examples. The first checks to see if it was defined and the second sets a variable to the value.

```
<cfif isDefined("URL.id")>
  <cset myVariable = URL.id>
</cfif>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Modified to remove extraneous pound signs